# WSO2 Eclipse Luna datamapper loading Error

Tags: java, eclipse, wso2, wso2-esb

When I create SampleAIP.xml and add datamapper. It not working. following exception thrown in eclipse.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.custom.deserializer.DataMapperMediatorDeserializer.setInputDataType(DataMapperMediatorDeserializer.java:94)
 at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.custom.deserializer.DataMapperMediatorDeserializer.createNode(DataMapperMediatorDeserializer.java:38)
 at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.custom.deserializer.DataMapperMediatorDeserializer.createNode(DataMapperMediatorDeserializer.java:1)
 at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.custom.deserializer.AbstractEsbNodeDeserializer.executeMediatorDeserializer(AbstractEsbNodeDeserializer.java:248)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new versions of eclipse you cannot download the WSO2 development studio directly since its a third party software. In order to install development studio for new versions of eclipse you have to follow this link [Installing WSO2 ESB Tooling](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Installing+WSO2+ESB+Tooling). You can directly install WSO2 ESB to older versions (Luna) by the marketplace. But not for new versions of eclipse.
I could able to install WSO2 ESB to eclipse oxygen by using following above link. Hope this would work for you rather than using older versions of eclipse and WSO2 development studio. Above link will download and install WSO2 development studio 4.1.0. Cheers..!

[image]